# while conditional inside coroutine does not loop, hangs

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, while-loop

I have a coroutine that I want to contain a 2 second pause. I use a while loop that checks the diff between `initialTime` and `now` to check how long it's been:

```
IEnumerator MyCoroutine(){
    Debug.Log("Before the counter");

    //`Time.time` returns the number of seconds since app launch (i.e., `72.33448`)
    float initialTime = Time.time;
    Debug.Log("initialTime = " + initialTime);
    float now = initialTime;

    while(now - initialTime < 2.0f){
        yield return null;
        now = Time.time;
        Debug.Log("now = " + now);
    }

    Debug.Log("After the counter");

    //...Stuff that happens after delay
}
```

For some reason, about 1/5 times I run it, it will not exactly *hang* in the loop, but will fail to execute the entire coroutine: in the console I see that `Debug.Log("now = " + now);` only executes once and `Debug.Log("After the counter");` never happens— I'd expect a proper while loop hang to print `Debug.Log("now = " + now);` infinitely.

What could be wrong with the logic around this timer that could cause this behavior?

**Edit**: I'd prefer to stick to Unity's norms of using `StartCoroutine()` and `StopCoroutine()` rather than `System.Threading` if possible.

Comment: Why are you returning an `IEnumerator` rather than `IEnumerable`? I'm not a Unity person, so I don't know if this is a Unity thing.

Comment: Because I didn't know `IEnumerable` was a thing :P ... looking into it out now.

Comment: As Vikhram says, there doesn't seem to be a reason to use `IEnumerator` or `IEnumerable` at all - you're not returning any meaningful data. Thread.Sleep will work just fine for pausing your thread.

Comment: @gunr2171 I'm still trying to understand the difference but to be clear: I'm treating `MyCoroutine()` like a `void` method that just needs to do stuff concurrently, but after a 2 second delay. I edited the above code to reflect that more stuff will happen in the `IEnumerator` (it's not just counting for no reason)

Comment: Unity co-routines are not just a bad use of C# `yield` but are also obsolete now that Unity supports `async/await` with `Task`s

Comment: @A__ You cannot call an `IEnumerator` as if it was a `void` method and expect it to finish; it will stop at the first yield and then do nothing else because you're not stepping it.

Comment: @gunr2171 Unity has a [coroutine system](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html) built around `IEnumerator`.  It's an older way of writing async code before Unity formally supported `async/await` and `Task` (as MickyD mentions).

Comment: Sorry, I have no experience with c# outside the Unity environment, I don't know what its differences/quirks are :/

Comment: @Foggzie ah, I see. I'm in the middle of writing an answer about using `await Task.Delay`, I might hold off.

Comment: @Vikhram "Why are you `yield return null` " because I need to use an `IEnumerator` (or `IEnumerable` I guess apparently) in order to call `StartCoroutine(MyCoroutine())`

Comment: ...plus the habbits one picks up by writing Unity3D co-routines (essentially creating C# _iterators that don't actually iterate anything and always return `null`_) will most likely lead to **rejected code reviews** when you try to repeat the pattern and submit code to your peers outside of the Unity3D world

Comment: @MickyD great to know, I will keep that in mind thanks

Comment: @Vikhram You should look into how coroutines work before suggesting solutions here.  Sleeping the thread would be an entirely unacceptable solution.  It would freeze the entire application for two seconds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is fairly simple.

First off, you NEED an IEnumerator like you had, not an IEnumerable as was suggested in the comments. Very different things.

Second, Unity has a built in function that pauses your coroutine for how long you specify. Use either `WaitForSeconds(2f)` (2 being the amount of seconds) or `WaitForSecondsRealtime(2f)`

`WaitForSeconds` "waits" for 2 seconds while taking framerate into account.

`WaitForSecondsRealTIme` "waits" for 2 seconds without taking framerate into account.

```
IEnumerator MyCoroutine(){
    Debug.Log("Before the counter");

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f); 

    Debug.Log("After the counter");

    //...Stuff that happens after delay
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was in the process of discovering WaitForSeconds() thanks to some clues from the comments above about returning something other than _null_, realizing I over-engineered a bit.

Comment: I haven't tested it but I think the difference between WaitForSeconds and WaitForSecondsRealTime is not related to the framerate. It's more likely for the non-real time variant to be based on Unity engine's timeScale (i.e. the speed of engine timings, say physics simulation).

Comment: WaitForSecondsRealTime uses unscaled time instead of scaled time. Unscaled time is framerate independent

Comment: @Immorality WaitForSeconds should also be framerate independent. Is should vary according to the timeScale just like Nikaas said, and not according to the freamerate.